# Ajax not working. I need the header and footer not to reload every time. Can you help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need header and footer not to change in some webpages so this is simple ajax code I have copied from stackoverflow.com. But it is not working. Please help me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#activities").click(function(){
                    $("#body").load("activities.html");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <a href="#" id="#activities">Activities</a>
            This is the header.
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <p>
                This is the body. 
            <p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">

            This is the footer.

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
<a href="#" id="#activities">Activities</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" id="activities">Activities</a>
<!.............^.......................-->
```

***Note :*** character "#" is not allowed in the value of attribute "ID"

Then add [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the browser default action on click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#activities").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#body").load("activities.html");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But header and footer are also gone.

Comment: @Parveen.gmp don't use `$("body")` it should be `$("#body")` , or try this selector `$("body #body")`

Comment: here are the files. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B57VOruceEjTMzc0a0s3WktGTWM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
id="#activities"
```

to:

```
id="activities"
```